# $A+USV^T$ is invertible iif $S^{-1}+V^TA^{-1}U$ is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I was tasked to prove the Woodbury identity and as an intermediate step I need to show that $A+USV^T$ is invertible iif $S^{-1}+V^TA^{-1}U$

$U,V\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ and $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, $S\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$. Only $S$ and $A$ are invertible.

---

My attempt was to assume $A+USV^T$ is invertible, then I could write...
$$(S^{-1}+V^TA^{-1}U)^{-1} = (S^{-1}A^{-1}(A+ASV^TA^{-1}U))^{-1}$$

My plan is to produce $A+USV^T$ in the brackets, so that I can invert the expression. But these matrices are not commutative, so I don't know how to get $A$ and $S$ inside of $V^T$, $U$.

Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Reduce to the problem $I+AB$ is invertible if and only if $I+BA$ is invertible, for which you can find many posts here.